# Existence of adjoint functors between topological categories

Tags: category-theory, manifolds, topological-groups, adjoint-functors

We have natural functors:

> $ Mfd\hookrightarrow Top ~~~~$ from the category of smooth manifolds to that of topological spaces,
>
> $ LieGrp\hookrightarrow TopGrp ~~~~$ from the category of Lie groups to that of topological groups.

So I am wondering if these functors admit left adjoints?
I guess that there are not such adjoints. However, I can not prove or disprove.
I also have seen adjoint functor theorems, but I don't know how to apply them for these particular cases.
Perhaps some necessary condition could be useful to disprove.

Comment: You can't apply the adjoint functor theorems because the category of Lie groups and the category of manifolds are neither complete nor cocomplete. You can't even guarantee that finite limits/colimits exist since intersections (fiber product) of two manifolds in an ambient manifold isn't always a manifold itself.

Comment: Exactly! You are right, but I am mostly focused on necessary conditions.

Comment: There are size restrictions on manifolds since they have to be second countable so if you have some really big space $X$ with loads of maps $X \rightarrow M$ there's no way there could exist a manifold $LX$ with the same amount of maps $LX \rightarrow M$ as there are maps $X \rightarrow M$. The counterexample I'm thinking of is if $X$ is some really large set with the discrete topology but I can't really fill in the details of the proof.

Comment: What if we assume our topological spaces to be compactly generated Hausdorff?

Comment: No, I still doubt that a left adjoint exist, intuitively speaking topological spaces are too different from manifolds for there to be a left adjoint. I'm still thinking of a proof though.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of spaces, note that $L(*)$ must again be a point, by the adjunction condition. Now $L$ would preserve coproducts, but arbitrary coproducts, even of a point, do not exist in the category of smooth manifolds. (To be sure of this, just note that every smooth manifold has cardinality at most that of the continuum, and consider maps from a big coproduct of points to the two-point manifold.) A similar argument works for groups, considering instead $\mathbb Z$.